# Is there a Perl interface to Mac OS X defaults?

Tags: perl, macos, defaults

Mac OS X has an application called [defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) which allows one to set and retrieve application configuration variables.

Is there a Perl module which allows me to read/write these configuration variables without having to use `qx//`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [`Mac::PropertyList`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Mac%3a%3aPropertyList) and [`Mac::Tie::Plist`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Mac%3a%3aTie%3a%3aPlist) modules, but neither supports writing.  Stick with `defaults` for now.